# SQL query syntax Error if append Go on top

Tags: sql-server, database

Whats wrong with the following query? However it works fine if I remove first "Go".

```
Go
if exists(select 1 from sys.objects where name='SP_xyz' and type='P')
drop procedure SP_xyz 
Go
```

Comment: Works fine here. There must be additional context to your situation that you've not told us about. And, you seem to have a solution (remove the `GO`), so why is that solution deficient?

Comment: Actually I have a script file with multiple stored procedures. When one procedure ends with go and then new starts as given in question it throws syntax error, I have hundreds of procedures in one file.

Comment: What is the purpose of first `Go`? its not required in your case.

Comment: How are you executing it?  In which client?

Comment: I am using SQLServer Management Studio of SQLServer 2008 R2.

Comment: It could be maybe an encoding problem of the script file itself.

Comment: What is the text of error message that you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

There are no need to first GO,

because GO is a command which execute the batch process. 
You have no any statement before first GO to execute.

Please refer below example with the comment.

The following example creates two batches. The first batch contains only a USEAdventureWorks2012 statement to set the database context. The remaining statements use a local variable. Therefore, all local variable declarations must be grouped in a single batch. This is done by not having a GO command until after the last statement that references the variable.

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;
GO
DECLARE @NmbrPeople int
SELECT @NmbrPeople = COUNT(*)
FROM Person.Person;
PRINT 'The number of people as of ' +
      CAST(GETDATE() AS char(20)) + ' is ' +
      CAST(@NmbrPeople AS char (10));
GO
```